# Get specific child of a specific child

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="row">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="row">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

New to jquery and was wondering how do you select a specific child of a specific child. Say I want to hide the second row from the second form. I've tried

```
$('.container:nth-child(2)').eq(1).css("display", "none")
```

and

```
$('.container').children("form").eq(1).css("display", "none")
```

but can't seem to get to the specific child of a specific child.

Comment: I wouldn't mix the `nth-child()` selector with the `.eq` method, it seems like one or the other should be used. Of course, this could be done with a single selector: `$('.form:nth-child(2) .row:nth-child(2)').hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use form as class.

```js
jQuery(".container .form:eq(1) .row:eq(1)").css('display', 'none')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="row">
        I am visible from form 1 row 1
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        I am visible from form 1 row 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="row">
        I am visible from form 2 row 1
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        I need to be hidden
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find the first element : $('.container .form').eq(1) then get the second element : .find('.row').eq(1)

```js
$('.container .form').eq(1).find('.row').eq(1).css("display", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="row">1
        </div>
        <div class="row">2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="row">1
        </div>
        <div class="row">2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```